# ArrayList is only copying last value from a delimiter file

Tags: java, javafx, arraylist

I have a library program that adds values into an array list, writes the lists to a delimited file. When my array list is getting populated, it only copies the last values. Here's the code I have right now:

```
// LibraryGUI.java file
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextInputDialog;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.util.Optional;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;



public class LibraryGUI extends Application {

   private Library library = new Library(this);
   private static Button btAddItem = new Button("Add");
   private static Button btCheckOut = new Button("Check Out");
   private static Button btCheckIn = new Button("Check In");
   private static Button btDelete = new Button("Delete");
   private ListView<String> list;

   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
       HBox buttonPanel = new HBox();
       buttonPanel.getChildren().addAll(btAddItem, btCheckOut, btCheckIn, btDelete);
       buttonPanel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
       buttonPanel.setSpacing(17);

       list = new ListView<String>();
       list.setEditable(true);
       ObservableList<String> allItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList(library.listAllItems());
       list.setItems(allItems);
       allItems.addListener((ListChangeListener<Object>) change -> {
           System.out.println("List View Changed");
       });

       BorderPane bPane = new BorderPane();
       BorderPane.setAlignment(list, Pos.TOP_LEFT);
       BorderPane.setMargin(list, new Insets(14,14,8,14));
       BorderPane.setMargin(buttonPanel, new Insets(0,8,8,8));
       bPane.setCenter(list);
       bPane.setBottom(buttonPanel);

       // Add Item Button action
       btAddItem.setOnAction(e -> {
           addNewItem();
           list.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(library.listAllItems())); // Update GUI
       });
       // Check Out Item Button action
       btCheckOut.setOnAction(e -> {
           checkOutItem();
           list.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(library.listAllItems())); // Update GUI
       });
       // Check In Item Button action
       btCheckIn.setOnAction(e -> {
           checkInItem();
           list.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(library.listAllItems())); // Update GUI
       });
       // Delete Item Button action
       btDelete.setOnAction(e -> {
           deleteItem();
           list.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(library.listAllItems())); // Update GUI
       });

       Scene scene = new Scene(bPane, 600, 600);
       primaryStage.setTitle("Lending Library");
       primaryStage.setScene(scene);
       primaryStage.setWidth(bPane.getWidth());
       primaryStage.setHeight(bPane.getHeight());
       primaryStage.setResizable(false);
       primaryStage.show();
       // Save on close
       primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
           try {
               library.save();
           } catch (Exception exp) {
               System.out.println("File did not save!");
           } finally {
               System.exit(0);
           }
       });

   }

   // Method to add an item in the list
   public void addNewItem() {

       String name = null, format = null;
       TextInputDialog dialogBox = new TextInputDialog();
       dialogBox.setTitle("Add Item");
       dialogBox.setHeaderText(null);
       dialogBox.setContentText("Name of Item:");
       Optional<String> input = dialogBox.showAndWait();
       if (input.isPresent()) {
           name = input.get();
       }

       dialogBox.getEditor().clear();
       dialogBox.setContentText("FormatType: ");
       input = dialogBox.showAndWait();
       if (input.isPresent()) {
           format = input.get();
       }
       library.addNewItem(name, format);

       try {
        library.save();
       } catch (Exception exc) {
           System.out.println("File did not save!");
           exc.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

   // Method to delete an item in the list
   public void deleteItem() {
       Object selected = list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
       String s = selected.toString();
       String title = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf("("));
       title = title.trim();
       library.delete(title);

       try {
        library.save();
        } catch (Exception exc) {
           System.out.println("File did not save!");
           exc.printStackTrace();
           }
   }

   // Method to check out item in the list
   public void checkOutItem() {
       String name = null, 
               date = null;

       TextInputDialog dialogBox = new TextInputDialog();
       dialogBox.setTitle("Item Check Out");
       dialogBox.setHeaderText(null);

       dialogBox.setContentText("Enter Person Loaning To: ");
       Optional<String> result = dialogBox.showAndWait();
       if (result.isPresent()) {
           name = result.get();
       }

       dialogBox.getEditor().clear();
       dialogBox.setContentText("Date: ");
       result = dialogBox.showAndWait();
       if (result.isPresent()) {
           date = result.get();
       }

       try {
           library.markItemOnLoan(list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(), name, date);
       } catch (Exception e) {
           Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
           alert.setTitle("Error");
           alert.setHeaderText(null);
           alert.setContentText(e.getMessage());
       }
   }

   // Method to check in items in the list
   public void checkInItem() {
       Object selected = list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem(); // gets the selected item
       String s = selected.toString(); // converts that to a String
       String title = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf("(")); // extracts the title
       title.trim(); // removes any trailing whitespace

       TextInputDialog dialog = new TextInputDialog();
       dialog.setTitle("Item Check In");
       dialog.setHeaderText(null);
       dialog.setContentText("Enter Title Returned: ");

       try {
           library.markItemReturned(list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
       } catch (Exception e) {
           Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
           alert.setTitle("Error");
           alert.setHeaderText(null);
           alert.setContentText(e.getMessage());
       }
   }

   // Method to start GUI
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Application.launch(args);
   }
}
```

This is my Library.java file

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Library {

   private ArrayList<MediaItem> items;
   private LibraryGUI gui;
   private ArrayList<String> masterList;

   public Library(LibraryGUI GUI) {
       this.gui = gui;
       items = new ArrayList<MediaItem>();
       try {
           open();
       } catch (Exception exp) {
           System.out.println(exp.getMessage());
           exp.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

   // Method to add new item
   public void addNewItem(String title, String format) {
       items.add(new MediaItem(title, format));
       System.out.println("Item Added");
       System.out.println(items.get(items.size() - 1).getTitle());
   }

   // Method to mark item on loan
   public void markItemOnLoan(int index, String title, String loanDate) throws Exception {
       try {
           items.get(index).markOnLoan(title, loanDate);
       } catch (Exception e) {
           throw e;
       }
       return;
   }

   // 
   public ArrayList<String> listAllItems() {
       System.out.println("\nItems Updated~");
       masterList = new ArrayList<String>();

       System.out.println("Number of values in Items: "+ items.size()); // Debugging console output

       for (int index = 0; index < (items.size()); index++) {
           System.out.println("Index for showing Array list: " + index); // Debugging console output

           String mItem = "";
           mItem = items.get(index).getTitle();

           System.out.println(items.get(index).getTitle()); // Debugging console output
           mItem += " (";
           mItem += items.get(index).getFormat();
           mItem += ")";
           if (items.get(index).isOnLoan()) {
               mItem += (" loaned to " + items.get(index).getLoanedTo() + " on " + items.get(index).getDateLoaned());
           }
           masterList.add(mItem);
           System.out.println("Number of items in Master List: "+ masterList.size()); // Debugging console output
           System.out.println("Added " + items.get(index).getTitle()); // Debugging console output
       }

       return masterList;
   }

   // Method to mark item returned
   public void markItemReturned(int index) {
       try {
           items.get(index).markReturned();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return;
   }

   // Method to delete item
   public void delete(String title) {

       Iterator<MediaItem> iter = items.iterator();
       while (iter.hasNext()) {
            MediaItem mItem = iter.next();
            if(mItem.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(title))
                iter.remove();
       }

   }

   // Method to save items to file
   public void save() throws Exception {
       File file = new File("libraryItems.txt");
       PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);

       for(MediaItem item : items) {
           pw.println(
                   "%" + item.getTitle() + "%" + item.getFormat() + "%" + item.isOnLoan() + 
                   "%" + (item.isOnLoan() ? item.getLoanedTo() : "null") + "%" + 
                           (item.isOnLoan() ? item.getDateLoaned() : "null"));
       }

       System.out.println("File Saved");
       pw.close();
   }

   // Method to open file
   public void open() throws Exception {
       MediaItem mItem = new MediaItem();
       String itemStr;
       String loanedTo;
       Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File("libraryItems.txt"));
       fileInput.useDelimiter("%");

       while (fileInput.hasNext()) {
           System.out.println("File opened!"); // Debugging console output
           mItem.setTitle(fileInput.next());
           mItem.setFormat(fileInput.next());
           mItem.setOnLoan(fileInput.nextBoolean());
           loanedTo = fileInput.next();
           mItem.setLoanedTo(loanedTo != "null" ? loanedTo: null);
           itemStr = fileInput.next();
           mItem.setDateLoaned(itemStr != "null" ? itemStr : null);
           System.out.println(mItem.getTitle() + " (" + mItem.getFormat() + ") " + mItem.isOnLoan() + 
                   " " + (mItem.isOnLoan() ? mItem.getLoanedTo() : "null") + " "  + 
                   (mItem.isOnLoan() ? mItem.getDateLoaned() : "null")); // Debugging console output

           items.add(mItem);

           System.out.println("Item added: " + mItem.getTitle()); // Debugging console output
           System.out.println("Number of values in Item: " + items.size()); // Debugging console output
       }
       System.out.println("Number of values in Item: " + items.size()); // Debugging console output
       fileInput.close();
   }
}
```

This is my MediaItem.java file

```
public class MediaItem {
    private String title;
    private String format;
    private boolean onLoan;
    private String dateLoaned;
    private String loanedTo;

    public MediaItem() {
        title = null;
        format = null;
        onLoan = false;
        dateLoaned = null;
        loanedTo = null;
    }

    public MediaItem(String title, String format){
        this.title = title;
        this.format = format;
        this.onLoan = false;
        this.dateLoaned = null;
        this.loanedTo = null;
    }

    public void markOnLoan(String name, String date){
        if(onLoan)
            System.out.println("This title is already loaned to " + loanedTo + " on " + dateLoaned);
        else {
            this.loanedTo = name;
            this.dateLoaned = date;
            this.onLoan = true;
            }
        }

    public void markReturned() {
        if(!onLoan) {
            System.out.println("This title is not currently loaned out");
        }else
        {
            this.onLoan = false;
            this.loanedTo = null;
            this.dateLoaned = null;
        }
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
        }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
        }
    public String getFormat() {
        return format;
        }
    public void setFormat(String format) {
        this.format = format;
        }
    public boolean isOnLoan() {
        return onLoan;
        }
    public void setOnLoan(boolean onLoan) {
        this.onLoan = onLoan;
        }
    public String getDateLoaned() {
        return dateLoaned;
        }
    public void setDateLoaned(String dateLoaned) {
        this.dateLoaned = dateLoaned;
        }
    public String getLoanedTo() {
        return loanedTo;
        }
    public void setLoanedTo(String loanedTo) {
        this.loanedTo = loanedTo;
        }
    }
```

And this is a sample libraryItems.txt file

```
%one%DVD%false%null%null
%two%DVD%false%null%null
%three%DVD%false%null%null
```

From my 'debugging' console output I can tell that in the "public ArrayList listAllItems" method is when the problem is occurring, but I'm not sure why. I have looked at similar questions and they don't seem to be working! A nudge in the right direction is appreciated!

Comment: You're calling `listAllItems` multiple times, yet `listAllItems` resets `masterList = new ArrayList<String>();` in the body. That explains why you only see the last values. Either you remove this line from `listAllItems` (assuming it's at least initialized somewhere else - or you change it to something like `masterList = masterList != null ? masterList : new ArrayList<String>();`), or you make your `list.setItems` method somehow *append* to its collection

Comment: @ernest_k No, it doesn't. Note that the `masterList` is only ever accessed from `listAllItems`. You could convert the field to a local variable as well and the only thing it would change is the code quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for item creation resides outside the `while` loop in `open()`. This results in only one instance per call being created. This instance is repeatedly updated.

You need to move the item creation inside the loop body:

```
   public void open() throws Exception {

       try (Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File("libraryItems.txt"))) { // try-with resources makes sure that the Scanner is closed even on an error

          fileInput.useDelimiter("%");

          System.out.println("File opened!"); // Debugging console output

           while (fileInput.hasNext()) {
               MediaItem mItem = new MediaItem(); // create one item per line
               mItem.setTitle(fileInput.next());
               mItem.setFormat(fileInput.next());
               mItem.setOnLoan(fileInput.nextBoolean());

               String loanedTo = fileInput.next();
               mItem.setLoanedTo(loanedTo != "null" ? loanedTo: null);

               String itemStr = fileInput.next();
               mItem.setDateLoaned(itemStr != "null" ? itemStr : null);

               System.out.println(mItem.getTitle() + " (" + mItem.getFormat() + ") " + mItem.isOnLoan() + 
                       " " + (mItem.isOnLoan() ? mItem.getLoanedTo() : "null") + " "  + 
                       (mItem.isOnLoan() ? mItem.getDateLoaned() : "null")); // Debugging console output

               items.add(mItem);

               System.out.println("Item added: " + mItem.getTitle()); // Debugging console output
               System.out.println("Number of values in Item: " + items.size()); // Debugging console output
           }
           System.out.println("Number of values in Item: " + items.size()); // Debugging console output
       }
   }
```

Comment: @ernest_k I tried all of your suggestions and wasn't able to get any of the solutions to work but thank you for your advice!

Comment: @Abra Thanks! That worked in reading the file contents correctly!